# try to render todo item as <li>, but todo.name is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a todo-list app and encounter this problem:

If I put the Todo component inside the TodoList component and the todo item is passed as a prop
`todo = {name: "ssss", status: false, id: 0.028982865008862824}`

the `todo.name` will be undefined if I need to access it inside the Todo component

```
// TodoList.js
import React from "react";

export default function TodoList({ todos }) {
  function Todo({ todo }) {
    console.log(todo);       // will print todo as an object 
                             // {name: "xxxx", id: "12334", status: false}
    console.log(todo.name);  // undefined
    return (
      <div className="todo">
        <li className="todo-item"></li>
          <button className="complete-button">
             <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
          </button>
          <button className="trash-button">
             <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
          </button>
       </div>
    );
   }
  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo}></Todo>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if I changed this to seperate components as two seperate components and pass the todo item as a prop, it will work. Why is this happening?

```
// TodoList.js
import React from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

export default function TodoList({ todos }) {
  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo}></Todo>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

// Todo.js
import React from "react";

export default function Todo({ todo }) {
  console.log(todo);
  console.log(todo.name); // will print the name
  return (
    <div className="todo">
      <li className="todo-item"></li>
      <button className="complete-button">
        <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
      </button>
      <button className="trash-button">
        <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR You cannot define components inside another component.

#### I changed this to separate components and it works

That is because that is the correct way to do it! You **cannot** define your components inside the functions of another component. You can however do a function similar to this:

```
const renderTodo = (todo) => {
    return (
      <div className="todo">
        <li className="todo-item"></li>
          <button className="complete-button">
             <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
          </button>
          <button className="trash-button">
             <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
          </button>
       </div>
    );
   }

  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          { renderTodo(todo) }
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

But I would still advise against it. React is the most useful when split into components, as you did in your 2nd example, like this:

`Todo.js`

```
export default ({ todo }) => <p>{todo.name}</p>
```

`TodoList.js`

```
import Todo from './Todo.js'

export default ({ todos }) => <div>{todos.map((todo) => <Todo todo={todo} />}</div>
```

The reason 1st example is not working is because your Component, which you've defined inside another component is constantly re-rendering, and thus you lose your `todo` props, making `todo.name` yield undefined.